# Javafx aligning buttons as a menu BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

The buttons at this moment are all stacked in the left bottom corner of the scene. How can I move them to the right side so that they stay all aligned like a menu?

```
public class Mainfx extends Application { 
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
    Button btn1 = new Button("Botao 1"); 
    Button btn2 = new Button("Botao 2"); 
    Button btn3 = new Button("Botao 3"); 
    Button btn4 = new Button("Botao 4"); 
    Button btn5 = new Button("Botao 5");       
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(); 
    root.setBottom(btn1); 
    root.setBottom(btn2); 
    root.setBottom(btn3); 
    root.setBottom(btn4); 
    root.setBottom(btn5); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Border Layout"); 
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250)); 
    primaryStage.show(); 
} 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    launch(args); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the layout you want? "Like a menu" would imply you wanted them in a horizontal row across the top of the scene.

Comment: Look into [ControlFx's SplitMenuButton](http://fxexperience.com/2010/06/new-to-javafx-1-3-menubutton-splitmenubutton/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing the buttons in an HBox container will give you the desired result. Then place the HBox within the BorderPane.

```
public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button btn1 = new Button("Botao 1");
        Button btn2 = new Button("Botao 2");
        Button btn3 = new Button("Botao 3");
        Button btn4 = new Button("Botao 4");
        Button btn5 = new Button("Botao 5");

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(); 
        root.setBottom(hbox);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Border Layout");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not using Hbox, I'm using Borderpane. And the result of what u told me to do, makes the buttons float on top.

Comment: @fabimetabi This answer also uses a `BorderPane`. You said you wanted the buttons "Like a menu", which most programmers/users would interpret as meaning you wanted them across the top of the layout. If that's not what you want, you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with just a BorderPane. For the buttons to be at the bottom replace root.setTop(hbox); with root.setBottom(hbox); . I replaced it in the code as well so you just need to copy and paste. Sorry for the mixup.